# I'm a beginner of ASP.Net(c#). I want to build a simple threaded forum where clients can raise their questions and the answer would be given online

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5

I'm a beginner of ASP.Net(c#). I want to build a simple threaded
forum where clients can raise their questions and the answer would be given online. Could you please show me some sample source code? The
simpler, the better.

Comment: Why not start with some simple tutorials to get you started with C#? There a loads around and probably way better than somebody here posting some random code snippets.

Comment: I think creating a forum in itself is a project and cant be created with 100s of lines of code. If you want there are several platforms like dotnet nuke which you can use for this and customize as needed. If you run with its default setting, you will not need to write a single line of code.

Comment: c'mon Jeff give him the code!! :D

Answer (score 0):

have a look at following

Open Source - [**PunBB.NET (Forum engine)**](http://punbbnet.codeplex.com/)

commercial - [**AspNetForum 6.3.0**](http://www.jitbit.com/asp-net-forum.aspx)